# Having Two Self Submitting Forms

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible for me to have two self submitting forms on a single page. If yes how do I allot different blocks of code to each form ?

Comment: What is a "self submitting form"?

Comment: @EmilVikström Probaply action=""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a hidden input with two different values.

```
<form action="" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="form_no" value="0">
...
</form>

<form action="" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="form_no" value="1">
...
</form>
```

On the server side, different on the basis of `$_REQUEST['form_no']`

---

Or you could also add it as a name parameter in submit element.

```
<input type="submit" name="form0">
```

Use `isset($_REQUEST['form0'])` to differentiate.

---

Another way of doing it is to append a GET parameter to differentiate

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?form_no=0" ...>
...
</form>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?form_no=1" ...>
...
</form>
```

Use `$_GET['form_no']` to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Name your first form form_one, and the second form form_two.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form_one'])) {
    // First form was submitted
}

if (isset($_POST['form_two'])) {
    // Second form was submitted
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two forms can be placed in a code by giving them different names and keeping their target _blank

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="action.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form action="action.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit1'])){
// first form was submitted
}

if(isset($_GET['submit2'])){
// second form was submitted
}
?>
```

Each form has a different script specified in this example, but keep in mind that you can simply use the same php file for both actions, specifying a different block of code for each form (that's the php part above).

Someone may have a better answer, but this method has served me well in the past.

Comment: i got a doubt. you say two different names in the action part. they are submitting to two different pages. then how would this work ?